# Asian Option pricing payoff inequality

Tags: inequality, finance

I am trying to prove the following inequality:

$$ \left( \exp \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \log(S_{t_i}) \right) - K \right)^+ \le \left( \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n S_{t_i} \right) - K \right)^+ $$

I can observe the inequality when I use fixed numbers, but I would like to establish it for any set of positive numbers.

Comment: Does this follow from Jensen's inequality?

Comment: It quite looks similar, given that the left hand-side is the payoff for the geometric Asian call option and the right hand-side is the payoff for the arithmetic Asian call option.

Answer (score 2):

You need the AM-GM inequality:
$$\sqrt[n]{x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n} \leq \frac{x_1 +x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n} $$
(see, for example:https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Arithmetic_Mean-Geometric_Mean_Inequality )

Then you have for the exponential term (since nothing happens with the $K$ term or the positive-part term I'll ignore them):
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
\exp \left( \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log (S_{t_i})  \right) &=& \exp^{\log S_{t_1}^{1/n}} \cdot \exp^{\log S_{t_2}^{1/n}} \cdots \exp^{\log S_{t_n}^{1/n}} \\ 
 & = & S_{t_1}^{1/n} \cdot S_{t_2}^{1/n} \cdots S_{t_n}^{1/n} \\
 & \leq & \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n S_{t_i}}{n} 
\end{eqnarray}$$